# select / where mysql not selecting properly

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Ive managed to come up with this with some help, However for some reason its not working properly.
The whole line at the end with categories in seems to be pretty random i can`t quite work out what its doing.

Used or holding seems to be working fine as does the month and i believe it is working correctly if all items are in the general category but any anywhere else and it goes weird.

Would really appreciate some help if anyone can see the problem.

`WHERE  (Status = 'Used' OR Status = 'Holding') AND MONTH( Display_Date )=4 AND Category = 'General' OR Category = 'mountains' OR Category = 'rivers' OR Category = 'sky' OR Category = 'crass' OR Category = 'sea' OR Category = 'flowers'`

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`, so your conditions as it reads now is:

```
WHERE ((Status = 'Used' OR Status = 'Holding') AND MONTH( Display_Date ) = 4 AND Category = 'General') OR Category = 'mountains' OR Category = 'rivers' OR Category = 'sky' OR Category = 'crass' OR Category = 'sea' OR Category = 'flowers'
```

I assume you want this instead:

```
WHERE  status IN ('used', 'holding')
       AND MONTH(Display_Date) = 4
       AND category IN ('general', 'mountains', 'rivers', 'sky', 'grass', 'sea')
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it has something to do with parenthesis. I'm guessing that you'd like to put something like.-

```
WHERE (Status = 'Used' OR Status = 'Holding') AND 
      MONTH(Display_Date) = 4 AND 
      (Category = 'General' OR Category = 'mountains' OR Category = 'rivers' OR Category = 'sky' OR Category = 'crass' OR Category = 'sea' OR Category = 'flowers')
```

Keep in mind that `AND` has priority over `OR`, so without parenthesis, your original condition would be `true` as long as any of the OR statement is `true`, regardless the prior `AND`conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're saying that any result that matches any of the Category values you've specified (along with matching the checks against Status and Display_Date) should be returned.  If that's the case, you need to wrap all of the checks against Category in parentheses:

```
WHERE (Status = 'Used' OR Status = 'Holding') AND MONTH( Display_Date )=4 AND     (Category = 'General' OR Category = 'mountains' OR Category = 'rivers' OR Category = 'sky' OR Category = 'crass' OR Category = 'sea' OR Category = 'flowers')
```